# Replace table and its contents with preg_replace(case insensitive)?

Tags: php, regex

Here is my code -

```
$pattern= '/<table[^>]*>.*?<\/table>/s';

$html= preg_replace($pattern, '', $html, 1);
```

I have tried with - `$pattern= '/<table[^>]*>.*?<\/table>/i';`, but not succeeded. Any help?

Comment: try `$pattern= '/<table[^>]*>.*?<\/table>/si';`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because dot in your regex by default won't match newline characters. So you need to add `s` DOTALL modifier to make dot in your regex to match also the line breaks.

```
$pattern= '/<table[^>]*>.*?<\/table>/si';
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php for the modifiers (the letters at the end of your regular expression string, after the delimiter).

"$html" implies that you might deal with a longer string comprising **several lines**. In this case the **"s" modifier** will be your friend.